# Missing Spyder Dependencies qtconsole >= 4.6.0: 4.5.1

Tags: python, dependencies, anaconda, spyder

I upgraded to Spyder 4 using Anaconda today, but I got an error saying "You have missing dependencies! qtconsole >=4.6.0: 4.5.1. (NOK).

I tried upgrading qtconsole and Spyder using conda, but neither of these solved the problem.

Note: I'm on Python 3.7

Comment: Can you share the full list of packages and their versions?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile How do I do that? Apologies, I'm new to Spyder.

Comment: The output of [`conda list`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#viewing-a-list-of-installed-packages) should be good.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile IPython >=4.0     :  7.6.1 (OK)
cython >=0.21     :  0.29.14 (OK)
jedi >=0.9.0      :  0.14.1 (OK)
matplotlib >=2.0.0:  3.1.1 (OK)
nbconvert >=4.0   :  5.5.0 (OK)
numpy >=1.7       :  1.17.4 (OK)
pandas >=0.13.1   :  0.25.0 (OK)
pycodestyle >=2.3 :  2.5.0 (OK)
pyflakes >=0.6.0  :  2.1.1 (OK)
pygments >=2.0    :  2.5.2 (OK)
pylint >=0.25     :  2.3.1 (OK)
qtconsole >=4.2.0 :  4.5.1 (OK)
rope >=0.9.4      :  0.14.0 (OK)
sphinx >=0.6.6    :  2.2.2 (OK)
sympy >=0.7.3     :  1.4 (OK) Sorry for the weird list. I don't know how to format without it saving. Does it work?

Comment: Are you using Anaconda Navigator (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/)? I would suggest giving it a try, I find it makes things much clearer. You can easily tell which packages are in need of an upgrade, and have conda do so.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I am using Anaconda navigator. And I know I need to upgrade qtconsole, but it says the requirements for it are satisfied.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean by _it says the requirements for it are satisfied_, could you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I go into Anaconda Prompt, type in `conda install qtconsole` or `conda upgrade qtconsole`, and it says the install/upgrade requirements are met, but qtconsole is still 4.5.1., not 4.6.0

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I just looked at the environments, and qtconsole is at 4.6.0 for Jupyter, but not Spyder

Comment: That’s strange...

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It is.

Comment: @CodeBabylon what happens if you run `conda install qtconsole=4.6.0` ? If that fails, try `conda install --force-reinstall qtconsole=4.6.0`.

Comment: @CDJB Still says I have missing dependencies.

Comment: @CodeBabylon can you post the full error message

Comment: @CDJB You have missing dependencies! `qtconsole >= 4.6.0: 4.5.1` Please install them to avoid this message! _Note_: Spyder could work without some of these dependencies, however to have a smooth experience when using Spyder we _strongly_ recommend you install all the listed missing dependencies. Failing to install these dependencies might result in bugs. Please be sure that any found bugs are not the direct result of missing dependencies, prior to reporting a new issue. (This pops up when I open Spyder).

Comment: @CodeBabylon Argh that sucks. It installed 4.6.0 just fine?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It did. Ananconda says it's installed and that I can't update it anymore.

Comment: @CodeBabylon All all the packages in the environment are up to date, right?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, they are

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the update broke something within Spyder.

You can uninstall Spyder through the Anaconda Navigator, then click the gear on Anaconda Navigator to install Spyder again using the previous version.